# as3 and variableRowHeight

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid

variableRowHeight is available in flex like this :

```
<mx:DataGrid variableRowHeight="true">
```

how do I do this to a pure as3 datagrid

```
dg = new DataGrid();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy. You should be able to do something like this:

```
dg.variableRowHeight = true;
```

I'm pretty sure all the attributes available in MXML are just properties of the ActionScript objects.

If you look up the documentation for the DataGrid class (with a quick Google search, something like 'actionscript flex datagrid class reference'), you can see variableRowHeight is an inherited property from the ListBase class.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#variableRowHeight

Answer (score 0):

Its quite helpful to understand:

http://hansmuller-flex.blogspot.com/2011/05/datagrid-row-heights.html